# WordPress Cron Job Ignores Timing

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a WordPress cron job that should be running every hour. Here is the code I'm implementing:

```
function isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval( $schedules ) {

    $schedules['every_sixty_minutes'] = array(
            'interval'  => 3600,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 60 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
    );  

    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_cron_recurrence_interval' );

wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_sixty_minutes', 'payout_action_hook' );

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'payout_action_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_sixty_minutes', 'action_hook' );
}

add_action('action_hook', 'fire_cron_job');
```

I have the job set up to send a testing email whenever it runs. I should be getting them every hour; instead, I get them every five minutes. I've tried changing the interval, and even swapping 'hourly' into the wp_schedule_event call, but nothing changes this odd behavior. What else should I be looking to change?

Comment: what does `wp_get_schedule` return?

Comment: @rtfm `wp_get_schedule` returns "hourly"; I added the return to the test email, and both the initial email and the one that followed 5 minutes later said 'hourly'.